# Facebook like button links to the home page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a website with a like button to the homepage and several subpages with their own like button. When I "like" a subpage and I look in my facebook profile, the link that appears redirects back again to the home page. Can someone please explain em why this happens? Id be most grateful.

These are the subpages in question:
http://XXXXXXX

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On that page you have `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.waermepumpen.de" />`

This means that regardless of which page actually has the Like button, you're telling Facebook that this page is another way of accessing the canonical URL `http://www.waermepumpen.de`

You should set the og:url meta tag to be the same URL which users will use to access the page - in the example you posted it's `http://www.waermepumpen.de/waermepumper-des-jahres/galerie-der-waermepumper/no_cache/1/` - this should match the 'href' parameter of the  tag too.

Comment: The problem is, I have 3 like buttons on the page. On the sidebar widget and the footer I have like buttons for the Home page, so if I change what you say, wouldnt that mean that the others will stop working?

Comment: If the homepage has the appropriate OG tags, set the 'href' parameter for those Like buttons which should like the homepage to `http://www.waermepumpen.de`, and the href of the Like button for (for example)  `http://www.waermepumpen.de/waermepumper-des-jahres/galerie-der-waermepumper/no_cache/1/` to  `http://www.waermepumpen.de/waermepumper-des-jahres/galerie-der-waermepumper/no_cache/1/` - the og:url meta tag should be the URL of the current page

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand what you mean. Look at this page: http://www.waermepumpen.de/waermepumper-des-jahres/galerie-der-waermepumper/detailansicht-waermepumper-des-jahres/no_cache/1/uid/christian-killing/ The URL in the like button and in the meta tag are the same, and yet, it keeps linking to the home site :S

Comment: Did you check in the URL linter? (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint ) - doing this clears Facebook's cache of your tags. I just checked it there and the Like button is one for the article, not the main site - screenshot: http://imgur.com/8qRTF i checked and the link is a link back to this URL: `http://www.waermepumpen.de/waermepumper-des-jahres/galerie-der-waermepumper/detailansicht-waermepumper-des-jahres/no_cache/1/uid/christian-killing/`

Comment: Also, the Like box at the side and Like button at the bottom are showing 111 for me, and the Like button for that article is showing '3' for me

Comment: You were right. The Lint tool + changing the Meta tag in each subfile worked fine! Thanks!